# [Vue warn]: Property "xxx" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vuejs3

I'm getting this super confusing Vue warning and I can't figure it out:

```
[Vue warn]: Property "me" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <UserReputation user= {reputation: {…}, _id: '638f81dbb288267e6340ddbc', username: 'artsborba'…} class="mt-1" > 
  ...
```

Here on StackOverflow I can find more topics with this warning, but seems each one is a different case, and mine is just not making sense! My vue version is `^3.1.0`, vuetify `^3.1.0` and vite `^2.5.4`.

My component looks like:

```
// MyComponent.vue
<v-menu location="end" location-strategy="connected">
  <template #activator="{ props }">
    <div
      v-bind="props"
      class="user-info-container cursor-pointer"
    >
      <UserAvatar
        :user="me"
      />
      <div v-if="me" class="user-data">
        <div class="username-row">
          {{ me.username }}
          <AppIcon
            icon="downward-arrow"
            color="primary"
            class="user-menu-icon"
            :class="{ 'is-active': props['aria-expanded'] === 'true' }"
          />
        </div>

        <!-- HERE WE HAVE THE WARNING SOURCE -->
        <UserReputation :user="me" class="mt-1" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  ...
</v-menu>
```

In the same component I have the `me` set as a prop:

```
  props: {
    me: {
      validator: prop => typeof prop === 'object' || prop === null,
      required: true
    }
  },
```

Now, please notice that in the same component I have another one using this `me` pro (`<UserAvatar :user="me"...>`), which doesn't trigger this warning. Only the `<UserReputation...` component usage does! If I comment out the `<UserReputation...` tag, the warning goes away.

I already tried placing this `me` as a computed value instead of a prop, directly inside `MyComponent.vue` (it comes from a Pinia store) and many other structures with no success. Hopefuly someone can help on this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are accesing at **me** property inside your *UserReputation component*, but in the parent you are passing **me** to **user** prop, like this ***:user="me"***, so... you need to access to **user** prop instead **me** prop inside *UserReputation component*.

If this answer doesn't resolve the question, please share us the structure of *UserReputation component*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It lead me into the issue....The UserReputation component had a mixin referencing the "me" property (I guess that's why in Vue 3 we are moving out of mixins)